# Why is it 'doing something' rather than 'to do something' here?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive, extraposition

In the page of '[memory lane](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/memory+lane#:%7E:text=It%20was%20lovely%20finding%20our%20old%20photo%20albums%20and%20taking%20a%20trip%20down%20memory%20lane.)' in *theFreeDictionary*, there's such a sentence as follows.

> It was lovely ***finding*** our old photo albums and taking a trip down memory lane.

We should [use 'to do', rather than 'doing', after 'it's adj.'](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/infinitive4.html), right? Why does the sentence in that dictionary use 'doing something'?

Below that sentence in the dictionary, there's [another sentence](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/memory+lane#:%7E:text=To%20be%20quite%20honest%2C%20it%27s%20growing%20quite%20dull%20doing%20nothing%20but%20re%2Dvisiting%20memory%20lane%20when%20I%20get%20together%20with%20my%20high%20school%20friends.) which seems kind of similar and nonetheless bothers me.

> To be quite honest, *it's growing quite dull* ***doing*** nothing but re-visiting memory lane when I get together with my high school friends.

What's the grammar pattern behind these two sentences? I also wonder which of 'adj. + doing' and 'adj. + to do' is preferred under what circumstances. Seems that a common grammar book wouldn't talk about this.

Comment: I think this might be just a matter of "idiomacy" after a "verb of transition" (with a range of "final states") such as ***growing dull*** in your context. While l don't like infinitive ***to do*** one little bit in your exact example, I don't mind it so much in *It's **becoming embarrassing to do** nothing*, and it's effectively *unavoidable* in *It's **becoming necessary to do** nothing*.

Comment: ...maybe "verb of transition" is irrelevant. Or maybe ***becoming, growing,...*** count as "transitional copulas". I think all these examples still work exactly the same with the standard copula TO BE *(**is**)* - so ***growing quite*** can safely be removed from the example without affecting the scope of "valid Answers" here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply not true that "We should use 'to do', rather than 'doing', after 'it's adj'": it depends on the adjective, and the sense.

When the statement is an external judgment about the action - about its possibility, appropriateness, wisdom - we use a *to*-infinitive clause;

> It is foolish to go out in this weather.

> It is sensible to dress up warmly.

When the statement is about the experience of doing the action, we normally use an *-ing* clause:

> It is lovely walking on a windy day.

> It is tiring walking against the wind.

> It was fun sorting through those photos.

But we can sometimes use a *to-* clause when talking about a particular occasion:

> It was fun sorting/to sort through those photos the other day.

Please don't rely on grammar-quizzes.com: in another question a couple of days ago we found that it was full of unidiomatic English.

Comment: Fascinating. I briefly thought it might be meaningful to differentiate the two usages on the grounds that *It will be fun **to see / seeing** them tomorrow* could imply ***for me** too see...* or ***for you** seeing...* - but actually that doesn't seem to be relevant. But although I prefer the infinitive in your first ("foolish") example, I much prefer the continuous in *It's **no use complaining** - just do what she wants.* And surely ***no use*** is an "external judgment", so why is *that* one different?

Comment: Dunno. _No use_ is an odd one anyway: I'm not convinced it is an adjective.

Comment: Perhaps there's something in your "specialist knowledge" that makes you skeptical as to whether ***no use*** is an "adjective" (that's all way past my pay grade! :). But I see NGrams says [it's always continuous after ***no use***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%27s+no+use+complaining%2CIt%27s+no+use+to+complain&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) and [infinitive after ***useless***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%27s+useless+complaining%2CIt%27s+useless+to+complain&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 0):

> We should use 'to do', rather than 'doing', after 'it's adj.', right?

I don't see anything on the linked page that says that you can't use "doing" after "it's [adjective]".<sup>1</sup> In fact, either construction (with an infinitive or a gerund) is possible. Both are examples of "extraposition" in which the subject is postponed and replaced by "it". Without extraposition, the sentences would be (for convenience, I've highlighted the extraposed subject):

First example sentence:

> **Finding our old photo albums and taking a trip down memory lane** was lovely.
> **To find our old photo albums and take a trip down memory lane** was lovely.

Second example sentence:

> To be quite honest, **doing nothing but re-visiting memory lane when I get together with my high school friends** is growing quite dull.
> To be quite honest, **to do nothing but re-visit memory lane when I get together with my high school friends** is growing quite dull.

It is common to extrapose subjects (as I did there!), especially when they are lengthy, as in those example sentences. ELL has [an extraposition tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extraposition) that contains some questions that you might find useful. (I've added that tag to this question, too.)

---

> I also wonder which of 'adj. + doing' and 'adj. + to do' is preferred under what circumstances.

I won't address this issue, because [another question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/291286/which-sentence-is-correct-and-why-gerund-vs-infinitive/) already asks directly about it. If you're still confused, you may want to edit or otherwise bump that question so that it gets some attention.

---

<sup>1</sup> That website seems to have problems. Within seconds I noticed a blatant error: "Restating a that-clauses as an infinitive clause". I'd be wary of whatever it says.